# Pull content from a file in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a file with the following content...

```
2012-09-19_12:26:01
UPTIME report
 12:26:12 up 2 days, 22:53,  5 users,  load average: 0.13, 0.10, 0.03

FREE report
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1914244     366692    1547552          0      85136     160928
-/+ buffers/cache:     120628    1793616
Swap:      4192956      35928    4157028

VMSTAT report
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----    
r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0  35928 1547552  85136 160928    3    4     4    79   16   40  1  6 92  0          0       

IOSTAT report
Linux 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 (progserver)        09/19/12        _x86_64_        (4 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           1.17    0.00    6.22    0.10    0.07   92.44

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
xvdc              1.92        23.72        30.26    6052098    7720864
xvda             11.25         6.00       600.34    1530740  153196208



Top 10 cpu using processes
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      9422  1.0  0.0  13492  1060 ?        R    12:26   0:00 ps auxww --sort=-pcpu
root       6520  0.2  0.2 143800  4308 pts/3    S+   12:25   0:00 vim LogicApp/Logic.py
root     28406  0.2  0.0  15024  1272 pts/4    S+   12:23   0:00 top
root         1  0.0  0.0  19228   292 ?        Ss   Sep16   0:01 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep16   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep16   1:06 [migration/0]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep16   0:02 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep16   0:00 [migration/0]

Top 10 memory using processes
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      6520  0.2  0.2 143800  4308 pts/3    S+   12:25   0:00 vim LogicApp/Logic.py
postfix  12145  0.0  0.1  78752  3204 ?        S    11:36   0:00 pickup -l -t fifo -u
root       928  0.0  0.1 251576  2956 ?        Sl   Sep16   0:08 /sbin/rsyslogd -i     /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 5
root      6521  0.0  0.0 140096  1336 ?        S    12:26   0:00 CROND
root     28406  0.2  0.0  15024  1272 pts/4    S+   12:23   0:00 top
root     31822  0.0  0.0 108428  1084 pts/6    Ss+  Sep18   0:00 -bash
root      9424  1.0  0.0  13492  1064 ?        R    12:26   0:00 ps auxww --sort=-rss
root      4936  0.0  0.0 108428   936 pts/3    Ss   Sep18   0:00 -bash
```

What I want to do is print a part of this file to a screen.  So for instance I want to take the following section of the file and print it to the screen in python...

```
Top 10 cpu using processes
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      9422  1.0  0.0  13492  1060 ?        R    12:26   0:00 ps auxww --sort=-pcpu
root       6520  0.2  0.2 143800  4308 pts/3    S+   12:25   0:00 vim LogicApp/Logic.py
root     28406  0.2  0.0  15024  1272 pts/4    S+   12:23   0:00 top
root         1  0.0  0.0  19228   292 ?        Ss   Sep16   0:01 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep16   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep16   1:06 [migration/0]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep16   0:02 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep16   0:00 [migration/0]
```

I believe this will be regex.  I want to match the line that says cpu to the line that says memory.

Any ideas how I would accomplish this?

Comment: What about the line that starts with `avg-cpu`?  I think you need to give us more constraints on what needs to be on the line for it to match.

Answer (score 4):

Using a regex for this is overkill; you basically want to extract the content between two lines. Here's an example on how to do this:

```
cpu = []
with open('filename') as f:
    in_cpu = False
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == 'Top 10 cpu using processes':
            in_cpu = True
        elif line == 'Top 10 memory using processes':
            break
        elif in_cpu and line:
            cpu.append(line)
```

If reading the whole file into memory is not an issue you can do it a bit nicer:

```
data = map(str.rstrip, open('filename'))
start_index = data.index('Top 10 cpu using processes')
end_index = data.index('Top 10 memory using processes')
cpu = data[start_index+1:end_index-1]
```

Note that `.index() will raise an exception in case no element is found! You need to use a`try..except` block to avoid this.

The `+1` of the start index excludes the "Top 10 ..." line; the `-1` excludes the empty line before the end marker.

Comment: In this case please accept the answer by clicking the gray checkmark icon on the left side.